# R not completing function call from within for loop

Tags: r, function, dataframe, ggmap

So this one I just can't figure out. I have a function that creates a heatmap.

```
createHeatMap <- function(mapData){
  ggmap(mapImageData1, extent = 'device') +
    geom_density2d(data = mapData, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 0.3) +
    stat_density2d(data = mapData, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
    scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE);
};
```

This works when I pass a dataframe to it. However, when I try to iterate through a for loop and make multiple maps nothing happens.

```
Users <- unique(baitStations$User);
for (user in Users){
  userData <- subset(baitStations, baitStations$User == user);
  createHeatMap(userData);
};
```

But when I make the call outside of the for loop it works.

```
for (user in Users){
  userData <- subset(baitStations, baitStations$User == user);
  createHeatMap(userData);
};

**createHeatMap(userData);**
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is blocking this from running? If I `head(userData)` from within the for loop it prints out the dataframe rows. So it's getting the dataframe.

Comment: Probably not `print`-ing.  (the FAQ about grid functions.)

Comment: Lazy loading may be at work. Try encapsulating the plotting in print() . `print( plot_here )` and see if it works , even though it seems the oddest thing in the world.

Comment: Put this in answers dude and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this dilemma as mentioned in the comments was to print() the heat map.